# TeamCity - deployment to multiple environments

Tags: deployment, automation, teamcity, web-deployment

I am using **TeamCity** to automate the deployment process. Now, I have like 3 different environments as below.

1. Development
2. Staging
3. Production

I have automated the process for staging environment. So my question is,

- Is it possible to automate to production environment from staging? And I also want to achieve automation for some specific instances(I don't want to deploy on production on every successful deployment on staging).
- I would like to know your thoughts about automation for production environment(Risk factors for production automation).

Comment: If you're using .NET you could try the (free) community version of Octopus Deploy, it might be more suitable for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to deploy. Have you written some scripts for deployment?

Comment: @Nadeem: I'm trying to deploy .Net web applications. I have used TeamCity scripts for automation for staging environment.